# How to get the distance from iBeacon to Android device

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I developed an `iBeacon` related app and I want to calculate the exact distance from `iBeacon` to an Android device. Is there any approach to get the exact distance in meters for Samsung Galaxy J7?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: The Android Beacon Library has support for this. See:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library

Comment: @PaulT: i am using iBeacon Library in my project.i am tring to do this way.https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/tree/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/distance and https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/resources/model-distance-calculations.json
 can tou check this and let me know if this is the way we can do ?thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the exact distance. `iBeacon` is not designed for.

An approximation of the distance is the more that you can get.

> For a beacon that is 5 meters away, distance estimates might fluctuate between 2 meters and 10 meters.
>   The reasons for these distance estimate variations and the steps that can be taken to reduce them are some of the most frequent questions we get about beacons. Factors that influence the error in the estimate include reflections of the radio signal, obstructions that attenuate the radio signal, and orientation of both the phone and the beacon.
>   [source](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html)

Comment: i am getting the distance but y it is changing within the meters.i want to get the distance constantly .when i kept a beacon at one meter distance its giving distance 0.8,1.38,2.66,3.84,6.8.its flaxuating in between.anyone hepl..

Comment: Like I said, you can't. It's impossible because of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The beacon provider /manufacturer would have their sdk. Use it in your eclipse project and directly you can get the distance in metres. I can send you my code if you want.

Comment: Yes pleace can you send me the code in detail.ancykuwel05@gmail.com.thanks for help

Comment: Yup sure i will send you in a while :)

Comment: Your gmail id is incorrect. I tried sending u email but it failed.

Comment: ancykuwel05@gmail.com